# JAVA Stream API -> Check for element in two lists depending on condition

Tags: java-8, stream

I have two List of type List<Map<String, Object>> .
List<Map<String, Object>> list1 and List<Map<String, Object>> list2

I want the entry of list2 if entry is there in list2 . If the specific entry is not there in list2, I want the list1 data to be retrieved.

list1 will always have the data , and list2 will have some data upon some condition.

How to achieve this in Stream API

I have two List of type List<Map<String, Object>> . List<Map<String, Object>> list1 and List<Map<String, Object>> list2

I want the entry of list2 if entry is there in list2 . If the specific entry is not there in list2, I want the list1 data to be retrieved.

list1 will always have the data , and list2 will have some data upon some condition.

How to achieve this in Stream API

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listFiltered = liat1.stream().filter(data -> {
                
   List<Map<String, Object>> list = list2.stream()
                                         .filter(t -> t.get("key") != null 
&&  t.get("key").equals( data.get("key"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
                if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is a job for `map()`, not `filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use concat with  your custom logic to select entry  in case of entry exist in list2 otherwise it will take from list 1 as shown in below example.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
    Map<String, Object> indiaMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    indiaMap1.put("stdcode", 91);
    indiaMap1.put("ISO", "IND");

    Map<String, Object> usaMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    usaMap1.put("stdcode", 1);
    usaMap1.put("ISO", "USA");

    List<Map<String, Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(Map.of("India", indiaMap1));
    list1.add(Map.of("USA", usaMap1));

    // Second List (with updated or new entries)
    Map<String, Object> indiaMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    indiaMap2.put("stdcode", 92); // Updated stdcode for India
    indiaMap2.put("ISO", "IND");

   /* Map<String, Object> canadaMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    canadaMap2.put("stdcode", 2);
    canadaMap2.put("ISO", "CAN"); */

    List<Map<String, Object>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(Map.of("India", indiaMap2));
    //list2.add(Map.of("Canada", canadaMap2));

    // Merging lists
    List<Map<String, Object>> mergedList = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            map -> map.keySet().iterator().next(), // Assumes each map has only one key
            Function.identity(),
            (mapFromList1, mapFromList2) -> mapFromList2 // Prioritize entry from list2
        ))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Output the merged list
    mergedList.forEach(System.out::println);
        

    }
}
```